# How does this if all statement work? Euler 7

Tags: python

I was looking at the code below and I can't seem to get my head around line 6 with the if all statement.
Could someone explain what it is doing and what happens in the first iteration when the list is empty. This is from Euler 7

```
def main():
    number_prime_to_find = 1001
    x = 2
    list_of_primes = []
    while (len(list_of_primes) < number_prime_to_find):
        if all(x % prime for prime in list_of_primes):
            list_of_primes.append(x)
```

Comment: is this code even giving u any result ?

Comment: I'm sure I have seen this exact question on SO. Have you searched it before posting it here?

Comment: ```%``` refers to the residual of the division between two numbers. So line 6 basically checks if  the residual of ```x``` and a ```prime``` number is different of 0, if passes this test for all the prime numbers in ```list_of_primes```  then ```x``` must be a prime and therefore appended to ```list_of_primes```

Comment: In the first iteration, list_of_primes is empty, so that list comprehension returns another empty list. So the term becomes  `all([]) `, which is True

Answer (score 0):

The block:

```
if all(x % prime for prime in list_of_primes):
    list_of_primes.append(x)
```

means "check that, for all primes in the list, `x` is not a multiple of that prime". It's effectively the same as (pseudo-code):

```
xIsAPrime = True
for each prime in list_of_primes:
    if x % prime == 0:
        xIsAPrime = False
        break
if xIsAPrime:
    list_of_primes.append(x)
```

If a candidate prime is not a multiple of any primes in the list, then that candidate prime is an *actual* prime, so is added to the list.

If the list of primes is empty (initial state), then the first number you check will be considered a prime (you're starting at `2` so that's correct).

The *reason* for this is that `all(x)` simply means "true if there are no falsey values in the iterable `x`, false otherwise". Since an empty iterable cannot have falsey values by definition, performing `all()` on it will always give true.

Following that (the addition of `2` to the list):

- The next prime will then be the next number that's not a multiple of two, so we add `3`;
- The next prime after that will be the next number that's not a multiple of two *or* three, so we add `5`;
- The next prime after that will be the next number that's not a multiple of any in the set `{ 2, 3, 5 }`, hence we add `7`;
- The next prime after that will be the next number that's not a multiple of any in the set `{ 2, 3, 5, 7 }`, add `11`;
- And so on, until the list size gets big enought that the final item is the prime we want.

Unfortunately for you, that bit of code doesn't seem to ever *change* `x` (unless you've just left it off in the question) so it's unlikely to give you what you want, *especially* since you also don't seem to print or return it. You can rectify that with:

```
def main():
    number_prime_to_find = 1001
    list_of_primes = []
    x = 2
    while len(list_of_primes) < number_prime_to_find:
        if all(x % prime for prime in list_of_primes):
            list_of_primes.append(x)
        x += 1                  # Need to modify x
    return list_of_primes[-1]   # Probably also want to output it.

print(main())
```

---

As an aside, you could further optimise this by realising that, other then two and three, all primes are of the form `6n ± 1, for n > 0` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431067/how-to-improve-the-efficiency-of-c-code-find-the-largest-prime-factor/32431097#32431097) for a more detailed explanation as to why this is the case):

```
def main():
    number_prime_to_find = 1001
    list_of_primes = [2, 3]
    (x, xadd) = (5, 2)
    while len(list_of_primes) < number_prime_to_find:
        if all(x % prime for prime in list_of_primes):
            list_of_primes.append(x)
        x += xadd          # Skip impossible primes.
        xadd = 6 - xadd    # Alternate adding 2, 4: gives 7, 11, 13, 17, ...
    return list_of_primes[-1]

print(main())
```

This is likely to be about (*very* roughly) three times faster, since you only need to check two candidates in each group of six numbers, rather than the original six candidates.

---

You may also want to consider making it a more generic function. While finding the 1001st prime is something we all want to do three or four times a day, you may want to avoid having to write a whole *other* function should some new starter on the team decide they want to get the 1002nd :-)

Something like this, I would imagine:

```
def getNthPrime(n):
    # Cater for smart-alecs :-)

    if n < 1: return None

    # Initial list holds those that aren't 6n +/- 1.

    primeList = [2, 3]

     # Next candidate and candidate increment.

    (candidate, delta) = (5, 2)

    # Until we have enough primes in list.

    while len(primeList) < n:
        # Add to list if it's prime, move to next candidate.

        if all(candidate % prime for prime in primeList):
            primeList.append(candidate)
        candidate += delta
        delta = 6 - delta

    # List big enough, return correct one. Note we use n-1 here
    # rather than -1, since you may want prime #1 and the list
    # STARTS with two primes. We subtract one because first prime
    # is actually at index zero.

    return primeList[n-1] 

print(getNthPrime(1001))
```